# IoT Broker seems to disagree with IoT Discovery

Tags: xml, fiware, fiware-orion

I have the next configuration:

```
IoTBroker(v.5.2.3)   <----->   IotDicovery(v.4.3)
```

when I issue a

```
GET ***/ngsi10/contextEntities/EntityName***
```

message to the **IoTBroker** it automatically generates a

```
***/ngsi9/discoverContext/Availability***
```

query to the **IoTDiscovery**. The **IoTDiscovery** then answers positively with a

```
 *200 OK* HTTP message
```

with the information about the *EntityName* required.

The problem is that when the **IoTBroker** makes the final response, it responds with a *404 NOT FOUND* HTTP Message.

This is the POST HTTP message being automatically generated by the **IoTBroker** to the the **IoTDiscovery**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<discoverContextAvailabilityRequest>
   <entityIdList>
      <entityId isPattern="false">
         <id>Room</id>
      </entityId>
   </entityIdList>
   <attributeList/>
      <restriction>
         <attributeExpression>
         </attributeExpression>
         <scope>
             <operationScope>
             <scopeType>
                IncludeAssociations
             </scopeType>
             <scopeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
             xsi:type="xs:string">
             SOURCES
             </scopeValue>
             </operationScope>
          </scope>
      </restriction>
</discoverContextAvailabilityRequest>
```

and this is the response from the **IoTDiscovery** to the **IoTBroker**, where apparently everything is OK:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><discoverContextAvailabilityResponse>
  <contextRegistrationResponseList>
    <contextRegistrationResponse>
      <contextRegistration>
        <entityIdList>
          <entityId type="Room" isPattern="false">
            <id>ConferenceRoom</id>
          </entityId>
        </entityIdList>
        <contextRegistrationAttributeList>
          <contextRegistrationAttribute>
            <name>temperature</name>
            <type>degree</type>
            <isDomain>false</isDomain>
            <metadata>
              <contextMetadata>
                <name>unit</name>
                <type>string</type>
                <value/>
              </contextMetadata>
            </metadata>
          </contextRegistrationAttribute>
        </contextRegistrationAttributeList>
        <providingApplication>http://192.168.100.1:70/tempApplication
...</providingApplication>
      </contextRegistration>
    </contextRegistrationResponse>
  </contextRegistrationResponseList>
  <errorCode>
    <code>200</code>
    <reasonPhrase>OK</reasonPhrase>
    <details xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Result</details>
  </errorCode>
</discoverContextAvailabilityResponse>
```

Comment: Not sure how this question relates with Orion (your diagram below "I have the next configuration" doesn't involves Orion), so the "fiware-orion" label. However, I'll keep an eye on this anyway ;)

Comment: As there is no "fiware-iot" label and the data is formatted in NGSI protocol the same way as Orion I decided to include the "fiware-orion" label! thnks @fgalan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should associate your context entity at **IoT Discovery** to a URL. Thus, the **IoT Broker** will start to send requests to the **IoT Providers** announced by **IoT Discovery**.

There is more information about the association process at **IoT Discovery** in this new guide: 
http://fiware-iot-discovery-ngsi9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programmer/programmer/index.html

Answer (score 1):

NGSI-10 and NGSI-9 relate respectively about context information and context availability information. In more simple wording, NGSI-10 is used for actual data while NGSI-9 provides information about data providers.

According to the documentation here (https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FI-WARE_NGSI-10_Open_RESTful_API_Specification) the following operation resource is a "Convenience Operation Resource":

```
/ngsi10/contextEntities/EntityName***
```

This resource is equivalent to a NGSI-10 queryContext. So looking at the introductory course here: https://edu.fiware.org/course/view.php?id=33 (slide 10) when you make an NGSI-10 request to the IoT Broker, the latter is looking for possible provider of such information by requesting the IoT Discovery. If the IoT Discovery reply with a list of providers, the IoT Broker proceeds to query the data providers. Then the IoT Broker aggregates all the replies from the data providers and finally answer to the request.
If any of the data providers do not have such context information or it is not reachable, the IoT Broker is replying with a 404 ContextElement not found.

Therefore you need to implement an NGSI-10 data providers which needs to expose the context via NGSI-10.

Comment: The **IoT Discovery** does reply with a list of providers (in this case only one) as you can see in the JSON reply (192.168.100.1). The problem is the **IoT Broker** is not querying the data provider. I have triple checked with Wireshark and the is no query from the **IoT Broker** to 192.168.100.1.